# How should I configure cron tasks to make them automatically run on GoDaddy?

Tags: cron

I own a lightweight blog hosted on GoDaddy. I could not get cron to automatically run, so I manually run it when necessary.

How should I configure cron tasks to make them automatically run on GoDaddy?

Comment: Always be independent from your hosting provider. What if you need to move to another provider tomorrow..

Comment: @SachinShekhar but there is a way to set up cron

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have much experience with GoDaddy (I prefer BlueHost), but you could use the [PoormansCron module](http://drupal.org/project/poormanscron) instead of running it manually. Also, if you update to Drupal 7 this is included in core.

Comment: PoormansCron works really well for exactly that situation.

Comment: +1 In Drupal 7, cron job is triggered by site visits. So, cron job schedule is independent from TOS of hosting provider.

Answer (score 2):

I used to use GoDaddy shared hosting and I had cron working with Drupal for a long time. I have since changed hosts so I can't lookup what my exact settings were. However it was something like this:

> curl --silent --compressed http://www.example.com/cron.php

Comment: Please explain more. Where to add this code ? Looks like i need to execute it manually like a cron bot `;)` ?

Comment: @NikhilM - Sorry, since I no longer use GoDaddy I have no more details

Comment: this not a real answer.